# Font is not displayed when I use it in Django

Tags: html, css, django, font-face

I placed the .ttf file and the html file in the same folder. In the html:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face { 
font-family: 'fontNameRegular'; 
src:local('fontName Regular'),
    local('fontName'), 
    url('Qarmic.ttf') format('truetype');
} 
</style>
<style>
#ads{font-family:'fontNameRegular';font-size:60px;font-weight:normal;}
#ads2{font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;}
</style>


<h2>System Font</h2>
 <div id="ads2">
     aaa
</div>

<h2>My Font</h2>
 <div id="ads">
     aaa
</div>
```

When I open the html file individually, it works.
However, when I use django to call the html file.

```
def view_preview(request):
    return render_to_response('preview.html')
```

The font will not show up. I really need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your font file in one of your `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Django won't serve the font relative to your HTML file. Rather, you'll want to move it and use:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<style type="text/css">
    @font-face { 
    font-family: 'fontNameRegular'; 
    src:local('fontName Regular'),
        local('fontName'), 
        url({% static 'path/to/Qarmic.ttf' %}) format('truetype');
    } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Django 1.8, but my problem was the name of **font-family** shouldn't be in qutoes!!I really really don't know why!!! But removing quotes,solved my problem,here is how I did and worked in an html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: Bnazanin;
        src: url("{% static 'font/Bnazanin.ttf' %}" ) format("truetype");
      }
</style>
```

I used this font in way that I add a this class so adding this class to a tag causes it's font to change! hope this helps you!

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .myfont{ /* my font class */
        font-family:'Bnazanin';
    }
</style>
```